# Unable to find Plugin

Tags: openldap, kerberos

I'm trying to execute this command,

```
kdb5_ldap_util -D cn=ldapadm,dc=c4ilietest,dc=com stashsrvpw -f /etc/krb5.d/stash.keyfile  cn=kerberos,dc=c4ilietest,dc=com
```

I get this error

```
kdb5_ldap_util: unable to find plugin [/usr/lib64/krb5/plugins/kdb/db2]: No such file or directory Failed to open file /etc/krb5.d/stash.keyfile: No such file or directory
```

I can't figure out the reason, the db2 plugin which it's complaining about is present at the location.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was looking at the same tutorial you were, and ran into the same issue. In my case, the path /etc/krb5.d didn't exist, but /etc/krb5.conf.d did, so I used that. Not 100% confident that fixed my issue, but you may try it yourself.